# Access an object from a broadcast receiver?

Tags: android

This is my source code of the broadcast receiver that I use to initiate Alarm:

```
public class AlarmReceiver extends WakefulBroadcastReceiver {

@Override
public void onReceive(final Context context, Intent intent) {

    PendingIntent sender = PendingIntent.getBroadcast(context, 0, 
intent, 0);


    Uri alarmUri = 
RingtoneManager.getDefaultUri(RingtoneManager.TYPE_ALARM);
    if (alarmUri == null)
    {
        alarmUri = 
RingtoneManager.getDefaultUri(RingtoneManager.TYPE_NOTIFICATION);
    }
    Ringtone ringtone = RingtoneManager.getRingtone(context, alarmUri);
    ringtone.play();


    //intent to call the activity which shows on ringing
    Intent myIntent = new Intent(context, Time_Date.class);
    myIntent.setFlags(Intent.FLAG_ACTIVITY_NEW_TASK);
    context.startActivity(myIntent);

    //display that alarm is ringing
    Toast.makeText(context, "Alarm Ringing...!!!", 
Toast.LENGTH_LONG).show();

    ComponentName comp = new ComponentName(context.getPackageName(),
            AlarmService.class.getName());
    startWakefulService(context, (intent.setComponent(comp)));
    setResultCode(Activity.RESULT_OK);

}


}
```

And from a different class, I am trying to call:

```
public void end(View view)
{
    ringtone.stop();


}
```

But, this definitely is the wrong way, I just need to know , what's the best and correct way of invoking this ?

Answer (score 0):

I would recommend a class with two `public static` functions accessing one `private static Ringtone ringABC`.
These two functions you can call playRingtone and stopRingtone and let them check in first place if there is ringABC (playing). (->to avoid NullPointerExceptions OR two ringtones playing)

EDIT:

```
public class MyRingtone {
    private static Ringtone ringtone = null;

    public static boolean startRingtone(Context context) {
        if(ringtone == null) {
            Uri alarmUri = RingtoneManager.getDefaultUri(RingtoneManager.TYPE_ALARM);
            if (alarmUri == null) {
                alarmUri = RingtoneManager.getDefaultUri(RingtoneManager.TYPE_NOTIFICATION);
            }
            ringtone = RingtoneManager.getRingtone(context, alarmUri);
            ringtone.play();

            return true;
        }
        else
            return false;
    }

    public static boolean stopRingtone() {
        if(ringtone != null) {
            ringtone.stop();
            ringtone = null;
            return true;
        }
        else
            return false;
    }
}
```

Comment: A simple edit to my code as an answer  would be much better, as I have trouble interpreting what you mentioned in the above answer :)